# Airflow space consumption is too high on the operating system

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

We have seen that on daily basis the OS level consumption for the airflow is very high. We have hardly 3 jobs which are getting executed. And the consumption is almost 1 GB per day. Whereas we have the database, which is on the different EC2 machine. But we are bothered about the EC2 machine on which airflow is hosted.

Any thoughts how we can manage the space, else we have to point these logs to S3 for the storage.

Please help with the solution how we can approach and steps.

As our environment is Airflow 2.5.0 on red hat linux on AWS